# How to get currently used SSL certificate thumbprint from MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell

So, how to get currently running SSL certificate (especially thumbprint) from MSSQL using Powershell? It could include SQL commands...

I know that it is in Windows Registry, but if you change it then it will be only applied after MSSQL restart.

So there is undefined blank space between configured cert in the registry and actually the running one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in the SQL Server log (openning it from powershell of with a sp_readerrorlog)

If you go with the TSQL approch, a script like this should do the job

```
declare @lastReboot datetime;
select @lastReboot = sqlserver_start_time from sys.dm_os_sys_info;
create table #loglist (id int, L_date datetime, size int);
insert into #loglist 
exec sys.sp_enumerrorlogs;

declare @LogID int
select top 1 @LogID=id from #loglist where L_date <= @lastReboot order by id;
set @LogID = @LogID-1;
drop table #loglist;

exec sp_readerrorlog @LogID,1, N'Cert Hash'
```

Comment: It works! Thanks!
I've tried to use PS, but couldn't find the SQL server start time (not using TSQL). If someone knows from where I can take it, then please add additional answer :-).

Comment: $Service = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE 'MSSQLServer'"|select ProcessId
$process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($Service.ProcessId)"
$process.CreationDate